# I already set the actionbar but getSupportActionBar() returns null

Tags: android, android-actionbar

If I go to another activity, it will crash and say my action bar is `null`
I already set it but why it's still be null? Can someone help me?

My manifest code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DaftarMurid"
        android:label="Daftar Murid" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".Main">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="arvin.a8c_smpbruder.Main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JadwalPelajaran"
        android:label="Jadwal Pelajaran" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UploadFoto"
        android:label="Upload Foto" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GaleriFoto"
        android:label="Galeri" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="Tentang" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Contributors"
        android:label="Kontributor" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadingHome"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TampilanAkun"
        android:label="Akun" />
    <activity android:name=".JadwalPiket"></activity>
</application>
```

My Main Activity Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //signIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

I set the actionbar on there, but still null. Can someone help me ?

My main activity layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="arvin.a8c_smpbruder.Main">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: where are you retrieving the actionbar? post also the xml of main activity and your toolbar xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Styles.xml if there the current style support the ActionBar.
Or check the activity your going to start support the ActionBar and try removing the label tag in your second activity.

Comment: still null sir :(

Comment: oh it's fixed, i follow some style.xml from another project. thanks man :)

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely missing the toolbar on you activity xml, add this at the top of your layout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Make sure your activity **extends** *AppCompatActivity*

If it still failing you can check [Setting Up the App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) by **Google Developers**, it's a complete and very comprehensive guide so you can compare what could be missing

Hope it helps

Comment: i added it sir, and its still null. sorry its my bad forget to upload the xml file

Comment: Make sure your activity is extending AppCompatActivity, if it still failing checkout the official guide https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and I just solved it, simple.

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.id_include);
```

"id_include"  is the **id** of the **include tag**

Comment: in xml file you will find the id name

Answer (score 0):

Check your Activity style. just add

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

and add this to style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```